# File Download via WebClient in Windows Service doesn't work

Tags: c#, service, timer, download, webclient

I'm trying to download a file in a windows service.

It doesn't work. If I copy the code in a Windows Form Desktop App it works perfect.

What did I miss?

```
    System.Timers.Timer LookupTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    string ConfigPath = "";
    string PricelistFilename = "";
    string User = "";
    string Pass = "";

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
      this.User = "USER";
      this.Pass = "PASS";
      //Read Config File
      this.ReadFromConfigFile();
      LookupTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(LookupTimer_Elapsed);
      LookupTimer.Enabled = true;
   }

    private void LookupTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
      string url = "https://mywebsite.com/file.csv";
      WebClient client = new WebClient();
      string basicToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", this.User, this.Pass)));
      try {
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", basicToken));
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DownloadFile(url, Path.Combine(this.ConfigPath, PricelistFilename));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }

    public void ReadFromConfigFile() {
      StreamReader loReader = null;
      string sPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "config.ini");
      string sInterval = "0";
      try {
        if (File.Exists(sPath)) {
          loReader = new StreamReader(sPath, Encoding.UTF8);
          string lsLine = "";
          while (!loReader.EndOfStream) {
            lsLine = loReader.ReadLine();
            string[] lines = lsLine.Split('=');
            if (lines.Length == 2) {
              string keyname = lines[0];
              string valuename = lines[1];
              if (keyname.ToUpper() == "FOLDER") {
                this.ConfigPath = valuename;
              } else if (keyname.ToUpper() == "DURATION") {
                sInterval = valuename;
                if (sInterval.Trim().Length > 0) {
                  try {
                    LookupTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(sInterval);
                  } catch (Exception ex) {
                    sInterval = "0";
                  }
                }
              } else if (keyname.ToUpper() == "FILENAME") {
                this.PricelistFilename = valuename;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
      if (loReader != null) {
        loReader.Close();
      }

      if (this.ConfigPath.Trim().Length == 0 || !Directory.Exists(this.ConfigPath)) {
        this.ConfigPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
      }
      if (sInterval.Trim().Length == 0) {
        this.LookupTimer.Interval = 3600000; // Convert.ToInt32(sInterval) * 3600;
      }
      if (PricelistFilename.Trim().Length == 0 || PricelistFilename.ToUpper().Trim().IndexOf(".CSV") == -1) {
        PricelistFilename = "FILE.csv";
      }
    }
```

The service should download every 1 hour csv file if file is on the server.

I tried to log every exception, but nothing has been writing in a log file. The log file even has not been created.

I have also tried to remove the timer to download the file one time, but it doesn't also work.

I have already used different users to start the windows service like an admin or the network service user.

Comment: [WebClient is not recommended for new development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-8.0#remarks). Although i don't really think, that's the actual problem.

Comment: Normally I would recommend you check the Windows Event Log for .NET Application errors. But I'm not sure you will see anything as you're 'swallowing' your errors with empty catch blocks; e.g. `catch (Exception ex) {}`.

Comment: Check the Target version of Net/Core for each project.  Most likely the target version is different in Windows Form than you current project.